# Garbled page output Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm migrating to Spring MVC 4.1/Tomcat 8, Java 8, and I'm getting a completely garbled page output on one particular page only. This did not happen, pre-migration and neither the template, nor the controller has changed as part of the migration. The problem occurs both in the development environment as well as on the test server.

The Controller setup is basically as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractContextSkillController extends BaseProfileController{

    public String skill(
            SearchProfileEntityVO vo,
            ModelMap model,
            NativeWebRequest request){

        [...]

        return "/profile/frm_skills";
    }

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/*/??_??/account/user/profile/edit/skill")
public class InContextSkillController extends AbstractContextSkillController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String skill(
            ModelMap model,
            NativeWebRequest request){

        if(myCondition) //if false => normal page output, if true => garbled
            return "forward:" + URLUtils.getBasePath(request) + "/account/user/profile/edit/skill/med";

        SearchProfileEntityVO vo = new SearchProfileEntityVO();

        return super.skill(vo, model, request);

    }

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/*/??_??/account/user/profile/edit/skill"})
public class CustomInContextSkillController extends AbstractContextSkillController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/med")
    public String skill(
            ModelMap model,
            NativeWebRequest request){

        SearchProfileEntityVO vo = new SearchProfileEntityVO();

        return super.skill(vo, model, request); // => garbled

    }
```

I modified the CustomInContextSkillController to return exactly the same content as InContextSkillController, and I still get the garbled output, when the only difference seems to be a different entry point, which surprises me.

All the templates are in UTF-8. I removed Sitemesh to return the pure page output and eliminate potential differences. If I keep Sitemesh active, only the part of the page, that represents this template produces the garbled output. If I retrun a new template, with just HELLO WORLD, it is also returned as garbled.

I tried various things, assuming this has to do with forwarding being encoded incorrectly. So I tried to make sure a characterencodingfilter as first by adding it to onStartup and also tried adding it to

```
@Component
@Order(10)
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext){
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncoding = new CharacterEncodingFilter();

    FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encoding-filter", characterEncoding);
    encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    encodingFilter.setAsyncSupported(isAsyncSecuritySupported());

    super.beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);


@Order(1)
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncoding = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncoding.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    characterEncoding.setForceEncoding(true);

    registerServletFilter(servletContext, characterEncoding);

    super.onStartup(servletContext);
```

I use Freemarker as template language. Any suggestions? I ran out

Comment: One commonality I'm finding is that the pages where this is occurring are the result of a spring "forward" action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was the net.sf.ehcache.constructs.web.filter.GzipFilter that was the culprit. Changed behaviour moving from web.xml to JavaConfig.

Comment: I am also facing a similar problem with Java config gzip filter. Could you please post the code which solved the issue?